# hacer las funciones en botones de menu JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito ponerle acciones a los botones de un menú creado en java con netbeans, lo hice con la ayuda que trae el compilador para hacer menús gráficos pero no se como hacer la conexión para que los botones ejecuten funciones, si alguien me explicara como hacerla por lo menos en cada uno de los casos con la linea de código para poder saber lo agradecería mucho, el programa trata sobre un sistema de pedido en el que tengo que hacer que se pide un producto y mostrar el producto que se pidió, agrego el código y una imagen del menú que tengo hecho. Lo que quiero es que en los datos del cliente se puedan agregar esos datos y en la lista de producto poder seleccionar algún producto y que se muestre en la tabla, y los botones de guardar para que se guarde el pedido esto si es solo como simularlo y el de salida que cierre el pedido.
[image: Menu]

```
package pedido;


public class interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public interfaz() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

    jScrollPane5 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    entityManager1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(null).createEntityManager();
    entityManager2 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(null).createEntityManager();
    query1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager1.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE unitsInStock > 0 AND p.discontinued <> 'y'");
    list1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : query1.getResultList();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    list2 = observableList (orders1.getOrderDetailsList());
    orders2 = new pedido.orders();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane2 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane3 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextPane4 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane7 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable3 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane5.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Sistema de Pedido");
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("OCR-B 10 BT", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(55, 5, 50));
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("SISTEMA DE PEDIDO");
    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft PhagsPa", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Datos del Cliente");

    jLabel3.setText("Nombre:");

    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, orders2, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${shipName}"), jTextPane1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, orders2, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${shipNumber}"), jTextPane2, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextPane2);

    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, orders2, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${shipAddress}"), jTextPane3, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextPane3);

    jLabel4.setText("Dirección:");

    jLabel5.setText("Cedúla:");

    jLabel6.setText("Telefono:");

    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, orders2, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${shipNumber}"), jTextPane4, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jTextPane4);

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft PhagsPa", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("Lista de Productos");

    jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/eliminar.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Eliminar");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/cancelar.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/guardar.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTable3.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Producto", "Modelo", "Cantidad", "Precio"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Object.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane7.setViewportView(jTable3);

    jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/añadir.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton5.setText("Agregar");
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(229, 229, 229))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(146, 146, 146)
            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(120, 120, 120)
            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 309, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 309, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 488, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                    .addGap(6, 6, 6)))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton5)
                                .addComponent(jButton2))
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 667, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(63, 63, 63)
            .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel7)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton5)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addGap(0, 16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    bindingGroup.bind();

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new interfaz().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager1;
private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable3;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane3;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane4;
private java.util.List<Products> list1;
private java.util.List<OrderDetails> list2;
private pedido.orders orders2;
private javax.persistence.Query query1;
private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en el código que te ha generado tienes este tipo de funciones:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Este es el controlador del jButton3 (Debe de ser el botón de cancelar de tu app), cuando un usuario haga clic en este botón se ejecutará el código que le hayas puesto dentro de esa función.

Para saber a que botón pertenecen los controladores fijate en las partes del código tales como:

```
jButton3.setIcon(...);
jButton2.setText("Eliminar"); // Añade texto al botón de 'Eliminar'
```

Una vez sepas a que botón pertenece cada controlador busca información para que al darle al botón de 'Agregar' su controlador saque los datos de los 'JTextPane' que son los campos de texto (deberá tener un método getText() o algo parecido) y los introduzca en la tabla 'JTable3' en su correspondiente celda.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han dicho mas arriba, al pulsar sobre un elemento doble click automaticamente te genera ese metodo.

De todas maneras, si quieres hacerlo tu sobre un boton solo tienes que poner hacer uso del metodo addActionListener, y dentro el codigo que pongas se ejecutara una vez clickes.